# Using variable in Windows FOR Loop

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd, window

What I'm trying to achieve is to take a user input which would be a term with numbers and letters and then use that to match directories in a folder and delete ones matching, here's what i have till now, but its not working,

```
@echo off
set /p:ID=Enter Search Term:
for /d %%G in ("*(%ID%)") do rd /s /q "%%~G"
pause
```

The output that i get if i turn on echo shows, that %ID% is not getting replaced with variable value which was the prompted input. Following is the output

```
for / %G in ("*()") do rd /s /q "%~G"
```

Can someone point out the error in this? thanks a lot

Comment: What's your error output?

Comment: i've edited the question with the output for reference, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
set /p:ID=Enter Search Term:
      ^ This colon is included in the name of the variable
```

So, you end with a variable named `:ID`. You can execute `set :` to see the variable defined.

To solve the problem just remove the colon.

```
set /p ID=Enter Search Term:
```